# CloudRun failing to server https flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, google-cloud-run

I have a flask python API exposed in a gcloud run instance.

This seems to works fine, but, some errors lead me to think that my https requests are being redirected to http.

So, to test it, I've added a before request controll, to avoid any none desired http request (I only want to allow https).

```
def beforeRequest():
if not request.is_secure:
    return Response(f"Invalid protocol. Received request was: {request.url}", status=301)
```

And, it seems to be the reason why my code fails:

```
$ curl --insecure --request GET 'https://test-aew1vewyw-na.a.run.app'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    93  100    93    0     0     19      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--    27Invalid protocol. Received request was: http://test-aew1vewyw-na.a.run.app
```

As you can see, I'm invoking a **https** request, but, my container gets a **http**.

Why would this happens? If I'm sending a https request, and gcloud is accepting it, why my contaier is invoked over http? Is there any way to look at it?

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-run-getting-started-with-python-and-flask/ is it helpful?

Comment: Hi @Divyani Yadav, yep, I have already tried it, but it doesn't work. It seems to be a https entrypoint, but redirect to http service.

This is the error I get from the front page:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// demo.a.run.app' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http:// test-aew1vewyw-na.a.run.app'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: You can't serve HTTPS from your Flask service, the TLS certificate can't be managed in your service, but in an upper layer, a load balancer.

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere you are right, setting up a load balancer will work, but, isn't it redundant? i mean, cloud run has its own scalability group

Comment: Hmmm, if you have only one service, in one region, yes it's redundant and more expensive (about $15 per month for the Load Balancer). If you use URL mask to route the request to the correct service, or if you deploy your services in several region and you want a routing to the closest location, or if you want to use Cloud Armor feature, Or if you want to route the same URL/domain name to Cloud Run, Cloud Function, App Engine, IaaS (VM, GKE) services, yes it makes sense.

Comment: Your app should be processing the HTTP header **X-Forwarded-Proto**. In front of your Cloud Run app is the GFE which handles all HTTP/HTTPS communications. The GFE will forward traffic to your app using HTTP. Your app processes the **X-Forwarded-Proto** to know which protocol the client used to connect. Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request

Comment: Your app will detect that the client protocol is https - Cloud Run now redirects users if they connect using http. Once the protocol is detected, your code should set the **is_secure** to false or true based upon **X-Forwarded-Proto**. If you add a load balancer in front of your Cloud Run service, you will have the same problem to solve.